# Birkhoff-von Neumann Proof inequality explanation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, stochastic-matrices, birkhoff-polytopes

> [image]

https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/n.s.walton/Notes/Hall_Birkhoff.pdf

Could someone possible explain how the inequality arises in $(44)$?

Comment: the link above is where you can find the PDF file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consequence of $P_{i,j}\geq 0$ and the fact that the sum on the right runs over more elements.
$$
\sum_{i \in U} \sum_{j \in N(U)}{N_{i,j}} \leq  
$$
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j \in N(U)}{N_{i,j}} =  
$$
$$
\sum_{j \in N(U)} \sum_{i = 1}^n {N_{i,j}}.
$$